# How to call Java class from Adobe air

Tags: apache-flex

I need to call a java class from my adobe air application . Is it possible.

Answer (score 2):

To call Java on the client side you'll want to use [NativeProcess](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/interacting_with_native_process.html) functionality, or a tool such as Merapi if you're building for versions of AIR before 2.0 .

To call Java on a server you can use either RemoteObject, or the WebService, or the HTTPService classes/tags.

---

Update: It looks like the Merapi Project site is down; I'm not sure if the project still exists or is available in any way.  But any "Java Server" you install on the client could work the same way that Merapi did.

Comment: I need to call the java class in the client side

Comment: can you provide some example link

Comment: @Nancy I updated my answer.  But, remember you can always perform a Google search for more information.  "Flex NativeProcess"  comes up with tons of information.